# NSWindow being auto released regardless of retain setting

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nswindow, autorelease

I created an utility NSWindow that does not have any views that I want to toggle on and off screen. I do not want to create it every time I need it to pop up. This is how I created it:

in the class interface:

```
-(void)blackOutWindowOnOff:(BOOL)onOff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSWindow *blackOutWindow;
```

Then when the app is being created I initialize the window and order it out to hide it:

```
NSRect e = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];
int H = (int)e.size.height;
int W = (int)e.size.width;

NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, W, H);
_blackOutWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                                styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                  backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                    defer:NO];
[_blackOutWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
[_addChildWindow:self.blackOutWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
    [_blackOutWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
[_blackOutWindow orderOut:nil];
```

Now when I run my toggle method which contains:

```
[_blackOutWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

the window is already gone. It has been released regardless of the fact I set retain on the property and also send it the message not to release when closed.

What am I ignorant of?

Comment: What's the `addChildWindow` line for?

Comment: Also, what is `blackOutWindow_` instance variable for? I hope you don't think it has anything to do with your `blackOutWindow` property.

Comment: I was under impression that I need to add the window to the window hierarchy for it to be shown, hence addChild. Am I wrong? I think I might be a little confused regarding the iVar as well. Is it separate from the self.blackOutWindow unless I @synthesize blackOutWindow = blackOutWindow_; ?

Comment: "I was under impression that I need to add the window to the window hierarchy for it to be shown" But you call `orderOut` immediately, so evidently you do not _want_ it shown. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You don't need an ivar declaration with a property. The ivar is synthesized. And when it is, it will be called `_blackOutWindow`, not `blackOutWindow_`.

Comment: I wanted to have it ready to whenever I want to toggle it in and out of the screen, but without it needing to autorelease, otherwise I would need to create it every time I pop it on the screen.